# Wrap an Objective-C class in a C struct to mirror class name

Tags: c, objective-c, class, struct, wrapper

Is there a way to wrap an Objective-C class in a C `struct` such that the `struct` name mirrors that of the class? I am ideally looking to imitate the behaviour of using [`extern "C"` in C++ as shown here](https://www.teddy.ch/c++_library_in_c/), rather than a having to point to a member of the struct of type `TestObject`, demonstrated in the simple programs below.

#### Wrapping Objective-C class to C struct

**testobject.m**

```c
#ifndef testobject_h
#define testobject_h

#ifdef __OBJC__
@interface TestObject : NSObject
- (void) printHello;
@end
#endif

typedef struct TestObjectC TestObjectC; 
TestObjectC* newTestObject(void);
void TestObject_printHello(TestObjectC *t);

#endif /* testobject_h */
```

**testobject.m**

```c
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "testobject.h"

@implementation TestObject

- (void)printHello
{
    printf("HELLO!\n");
}

@end

typedef struct TestObject_t
{
    TestObject *testObject;
}TestObjectC;

TestObjectC* newTestObject(void)
{
    TestObjectC *t = malloc(sizeof(TestObjectC));
    t->testObject = [TestObject new];
    return t;
}

void TestObject_printHello(TestObjectC* t)
{
    [t->testObject printHello];
}
```

**main.c**

```c
#include "testobject.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    TestObjectC *t = newTestObject();
    TestObject_printHello(t);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Wrapping C++ class to C struct

**TestClass.h**

```cpp
#ifndef __TESTCLASS_H
#define __TESTCLASS_H

class TestClass 
{
    public:
        void printHello(void);
};

#endif
```

**TestClass.cc**

```cpp
#include "TestClass.h"
void TestClass::printHello(void) 
{
    printf("HELLO!\n");
}
```

**MyWrapper.h**

```cpp
#ifndef __MYWRAPPER_H
#define __MYWRAPPER_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef struct TestClass TestClass;

TestClass* newTestClass();
void TestClass_printHello(TestClass* v);
void deleteTestClass(TestClass* v);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

**MyWrapper.cc**

```cpp
#include "TestClass.h"
#include "MyWrapper.h"

extern "C" 
{
  TestClass* newTestClass() 
  {
          return new TestClass();
  }

  void TestClass_int_set(TestClass* v, int i) 
  {
          v->printHello();
  }
  void deleteTestClass(TestClass* v) 
  {
          delete v;
  }
}
```

**C Program**

```c
#include "MyWrapper.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
  struct TestClass* c = newTestClass();
  TestClass_printHello(c);        
  deleteTestClass(c);
}
```

Comment: An ObjC object *is* a C-struct. `typedef struct objc_object {  Class isa; } *id`. This is how how CoreFoundation works, allowing you to transparently pass ObjC objects to CoreFoundation C functions. Look particularly at "toll-free bridging." https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Toll-FreeBridgin/Toll-FreeBridgin.html

Comment: Also, don't forget memory management. Your current solution seems to violate ARC rules, and you're not sending `-release` anywhere, so I don't see how TestObject is deallocated. I suggest spending some time in https://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-779.1/runtime/, particularly objc.h.

Comment: The example is kind of bloated as is, I've forgone `init` and `dealloc` to get something approaching brevity. Assume that is a separate issue, but yes, ARC would not be active

Comment: See https://github.com/iosptl/ios7ptl/blob/master/ch24-DeepObjC/Runtime/MyMsgSend.c for an example of managing ObjC entirely from C. I'm not quite clear what you're trying to achieve here with the wrapper. The ObjC runtime has a full C API. (myMsgSend is there to show how msg_send can be implemented by hand, you wouldn't normally need that)

Comment: @RobNapier currently using a C based SDK in which I would like to implement some native macOS features.

Comment: That's exactly what CoreFoundation and direct ObjC runtime is great for. I've built lots of those in C. There's no need for tricky wrappers coming from C. ObjC *is* C.

Comment: @RobNapier I appreciate that objc is a superset of C. What that rarely translates to is a simple example demonstrating as such.

Comment: Give me a few minutes to get Xcode upgraded and I'll write up a proper answer.

Comment: @RobertHarvey For this not to XY, essentially I just need to delete all of the example code. However at that point it lacks demonstration of an attempted solution and [helping others reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @RobNapier having looked at [previous github link](https://github.com/iosptl/ios7ptl/blob/master/ch24-DeepObjC/Runtime/MyMsgSend.c), from an Xcode perspective am I right in saying that I should just need to **1.** change the file extension from `main.c` to `main.m` and **2.** add `OTHER_LDFLAGS =  -Xlinker -U -Xlinker _objc_loadClassref` for compiling?

Comment: See answer below. You can can keep `main.c` in C. No need for `.m`. And that linker option is related to turning ARC off and I wouldn't do that. ARC is good. Keep ARC.

Comment: @RobNapier the SDK throws a `Non-trivial C types are disallowed in union` error across 10 files when ARC is enabled, so I'm not sure if I have a choice.

Comment: That would make sense if the files are .m, but why are there .m files in a C SDK? (If so, you can also turn off ARC for individual files.) But in any case my below code will work fine without ARC, too. I'll add an addendum

Comment: Nevermind. My code should fine when ARC is turned off. IIRC the ARC annotations just become no-ops.

Comment: @RobNapier Apologies, didn't look before I leapt. The entry point for the sdk is just a `main.c` file which I earnestly thought could be changed to `main.m` to expose using objc classes

Comment: No need for that if you use the approach below. You don't need to expose the C code to objc.h at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for a wrapper here. ObjC objects can be round-tripped through C without trouble, and can even support ARC. I'm going to change the style here a bit to match CoreFoundation. I'll write it again to show what it would look like without exposing the caller to CoreFoundation.

## main.c

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    // "Ref" means pointer. ...Create() means you must Release it.
    TestObjectRef t = TestObjectCreate();

    // Call your function
    TestObjectPrintHello(t);

    // And release it.
    CFRelease(t);
    return 0;
}
```

## testobject.h

```
#ifndef testobject_h
#define testobject_h

#import <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>

// Only define the ObjC part in ObjC
#ifdef __OBJC__
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface TestObject : NSObject
- (void) printHello;
@end

#endif

// This is the "void *" of CoreFoundation, but it lets the compiler know this
// this is a bridged ObjC object. This is the standard CF way of naming pointer types.
typedef CFTypeRef TestObjectRef;

// This is the standard CF way of naming functions. "Create" means you need to release it.
TestObjectRef TestObjectCreate(void);

// CF functions always start with their class
void TestObjectPrintHello(TestObjectRef t);

#endif /* testobject_h */
```

## testobject.m

```
#import "testobject.h"

@implementation TestObject

- (void)printHello
{
    printf("HELLO!\n");
}

@end

// ARC is no problem. We just need to tell ARC that we intend to keep an extra retain.
TestObjectRef TestObjectCreate(void) {
    return CFBridgingRetain([TestObject new]);
}

// And we can get back to ObjC using `__bridge`
void TestObjectPrintHello(TestObjectRef t) {
    [(__bridge TestObject *)t printHello];
}
```

---

That solution leaks CoreFoundation.h to the caller, and imposes CF-style naming. I happen to like that quite a lot in my systems. But sometimes I'm working on an existing cross-platform C system and you want to hide those details. So if I were trying to match the style in your example, I'd do it this way:

## main.c

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    TestObjectC *t = newTestObject();
    TestObject_printHello(t);
    TestObject_release(t); // Still need memory management. Can't avoid that.
    return 0;
}
```

## testobject.h

```
#ifndef testobject_h
#define testobject_h

#ifdef __OBJC__
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface TestObject : NSObject
- (void) printHello;
@end
#endif

typedef const void TestObjectC; // 'const void *' is more CF-like, but either is fine

TestObjectC* newTestObject(void);
void TestObject_printHello(TestObjectC *t);
void TestObject_release(TestObjectC *t);

#endif /* testobject_h */
```

## testobject.m

```
#import "testobject.h"

@implementation TestObject

- (void)printHello
{
    printf("HELLO!\n");
}

@end

TestObjectC* newTestObject(void) {
    return CFBridgingRetain([TestObject new]);
}

void TestObject_printHello(TestObjectC *t) {
    [(__bridge TestObject *)t printHello];
}
void TestObject_release(TestObjectC *t) {
    CFRelease(t);
}
```

Comment: Much more elegant. So that it can be recorded that I am not entirely mad, `CFTypeRef` only appears in [one other c tagged SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5Dtypedef+CFTypeRef).

Comment: The problem I now have is _Wrap an Objective-C class in a C struct to mirror class name_ is now a bad name for this question, as I was taking the wrong approach in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, that's why it was kind of an xy question :D (even if you did ask it in a perfectly fine way). I'd leave the title because it may help future searchers who are thinking about it in the same way.